# How to calculate a fraction raised to a power in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am working on a staking contract where users are penalized for early withdrawal according to an inverse exponential function. Here is an example of such a function:

`withdrawable amount = staked amount * ((1 - (1 - 0.0065)^T)`, where T is the number of days that have passed since the staking pool was opened.

The intuition for the formula is as follows, users will initially face a 100% penalty on the first day, and over time they will be able to withdraw a larger amount of their staked tokens. The value 0.0065 used above is arbitrary and only dictates the speed at which they "unlock" their staked tokens. In the figure below, the black line represents the amount of tokens the user staked, where the red line represents the amount they can currently withdraw.

[image]

That being said, I am aware of the issues surrounding overflow/underflow in Solidity, so I decided to approach this in the following way:

StakingPool.sol:

```
uint256 public constant PENALTY_RATE_NUMERATOR = 65;
uint256 public constant PENALTY_RATE_DENOMINATOR = 10000;
uint256 public START_DATE;

function withdrawableAmount(address _account) external view returns (uint256 amount) {

  uint256 timeDiff = (block.timestamp - START_DATE) / 1 days;

  uint256 amount = userInfo[_account].amount

  uint256 numerator = amount * ((PENALTY_RATE_DENOMINATOR - PENALTY_RATE_NUMERATOR) ** timeDiff);

  uint256 denominator = PENALTY_RATE_DENOMINATOR ** timeDiff;

  return amount - (numerator / denominator);
}
```

As you might have guessed I am encountering the following error: `VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x11 (Arithmetic operation underflowed or overflowed outside of an unchecked block)`, which I have confirmed is being caused by the line where denominator is calculated.

Comment: Can you include more details as to why that is the formula you're using, what is the 0.0065 supposed to be? How did you came up with that formula

Comment: @JulissaDC thanks for the reply. I have edited the question according to your request